# Record audio using recorder and then upload that on server android

Tags: android, audio, server, audio-recording, onactivityresult

I am trying to record audio in my app 
On a button press

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION); 
    startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_RECORD_SOUND);
```

But it is giving me error

```
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND }
```

but when i install any sound recorder from play store this error is gone but after recording the audio it does not return anything . It stay on the recorder window .

also what i have to write to get that audio file and upload it to the server

```
        @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code.

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setOutputFile(path);
//            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);         for mp3 audio
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

and path could be anything where file exists.for e.g.

```
path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/" + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/files/" + "myrecording.m4a";
```

Answer (score 1):

> But it is giving me error

There is no requirement for an Android device to have an activity that responds to that `Intent` action.

> when i install any sound recorder from play store this error is gone but after recording the audio it does not return anything . It stay on the recorder window .

That app has a bug, apparently.

> also what i have to write to get that audio file and upload it to the server

Quoting [the documentation for `RECORD_SOUND_ACTION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Media.html#RECORD_SOUND_ACTION), the output is "An uri to the recorded sound stored in the Media Library if the recording was successful". IOW, call `getData()` on the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()`, and that is supposed to be a `Uri` pointing to the recorded audio. Note that this does not have to represent a file on the filesystem, let alone one that you can access.